# Save data in txt

Tags: ios, xcode, storage, text-files, datastore

I got ios app. I need to store some data. I tried to do it in txt file like this:

```
[toFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

But when i dissmis view controller, where i save data, file's content is null again. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you're trying to write to your app's bundle. You can't. You have to write in either NSDocumentsDirectory or [app sandbox]/Library.

Comment: NSString *path  =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"user" ofType:@"txt"]; - is it wrong?

Comment: Yes it is. You CANNOT write to your app bundle.

Comment: Seriously, why on Earth are you downvoting this??

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you save your file inside the document directory, not the the resource directory, because you cant write to your app bundle.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"user.txt"];
```

Also check out the [iOS Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) (login required):

> 1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in
>      the /Documents directory and will be automatically
>      backed up by iCloud.

I think there tutorials could help you to understand how to work with directories and files on iOS:

- [Working with Directories on iPhone OS](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iPhone_OS)
- [Working with Files on the iPhone](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_on_the_iPhone)

Comment: where should i place my .txt file in project?

Comment: I updated my example. If you generate the filePath like that it should work :)

Comment: yeah. but where should i create this file in first time? your link doesnt work "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: You don't have to create the file … `writeToFile` will handle that for you. Just make sure you know where you stored it for reuse. I  guess putting it just into the Documents directory is ok. But keep in mind that you should not store sensitive data inside this file if you don't crypt it, because it's not really save there.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a `NSError *` parameter to your `writeToFile` and when `writeToFile` returns `NO` (which means it failed), you can print out the `NSError` information to help you figure out what went wrong.

For example:

```
NSError * error = nil;
BOOL success;

success = [toFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (success == NO)
{
    NSLog( @"error in writeToFile - %@", [error localizedDescription] );
}
```